# Custom Detail Page Button Not Visible In Lightning Experience But Showing Up In Classic Experience

Tags: lightning-experience, custom-button, administration, salesforce-classic

I have created a custom detail page button(onclick calling Javascript) that is showing in salesforce classic experience but not in lightning experience. I have added the button to the page layout. I don't understand why this is happening. Can some one explain it to me ?
There are screenshots of the detail pages :

Lightning:

[image]

Classic :

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can not call JS from a button in Lightning.

When transitioning from classic to lightning one of the things you should take care is exactly that.

SF considers calling JS from a button to be security risk and hard enforce good coding practices there.

You should design the same functionality using hopefully Process or Flow.
If they are not sufficient try with a custom apex action in Flow to do what you need there.

Or maybe custom Lightning component to make easier transition if you use Js a lot for your functionality.

Comment: Thanks for replying @Boris , I just updated my detail button on which I was calling JS , I just calling my VF page directly